# Getting text that user entered in an other class

Tags: java, swing

Alright, so I made a class to make a custom textfield.
The class extends a JPanel, so I can set the color of the border.

It looks like this:

```
public class textfield {

    public static JTextField textF = new JTextField();


    public static class TextField extends JPanel{

        public  TextField(int x, int y, int width, int height, String bgColor, String brColor, String fgColor){

            this.setLayout(null);
            this.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            this.setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(bgColor.substring(0, 3)), Integer.parseInt(bgColor.substring(3, 6)), Integer.parseInt(bgColor.substring(6, 9))));
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(Integer.parseInt(brColor.substring(0, 3)), Integer.parseInt(brColor.substring(3, 6)), Integer.parseInt(brColor.substring(6, 9)))));


            textF.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            textF.setOpaque(false);
            textF.setBounds(width / 20, 0, width, height);
            textF.setForeground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(fgColor.substring(0, 3)), Integer.parseInt(fgColor.substring(3, 6)), Integer.parseInt(fgColor.substring(6, 9))));
            add(textF);

        }

    }

}
```

Now this is an example:

```
TextField userName = new textfield.TextField(1073, 177, 190, 31, "000003006", "120090040", "255255255");
add(userName);
```

My question now is, how am I able to get the text that the user entered in the textfield? I know how to do it if I only use 1 textfield, but I use multiple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is very strange to me, and I suspect you're missing some fundamental object-oriented concepts and probably just tinkered with this until you "got it to kind of work".

For starters, I don't think these things should be `static`.  That would mean that there can only ever be one of them.  Additionally, this should probably just be a simple class and not this embedded class.  And fields on a class should be `private` and expose access only through setter/getter methods where needed.

Consider something like this:

```
public class TextField extends JPanel{

    private JTextField textF = new JTextField();

    // the constructor you already have goes here
    // replace "textF" references with "this.textF" as needed

}
```

Now you have a `TextField` class which *is* a `JPanel` and *has* (as an internal member) a `JTextField`.  None of it is `static`, so you can create as many of them as you want and each is entirely encapsulated.

Then, to access things in that `JTextField` object, you can expose more methods on the `TextField` object:

```
public class TextField extends JPanel{

    private JTextField textF = new JTextField();

    // the constructor you already have goes here
    // replace "textF" references with "this.textF" as needed

    public String getText() {
        return textF.getText();
    }

}
```

The `getText()` method we expose is really just a pass-through to the `getText()` method that's already on the `JTextField`.  We can expose as many operations we we'd like by creating more methods.  If there are *a lot* of such methods, it might be practical to expose a getter for the `textF` variable directly, though that would technically violate the Law Of Demeter.